Why is the style of <div> on the page not updating?
I'm making a project in Django. I ran into a problem. I have div containers with dynamic IDs. I load the ID from the database and automatically upload it to HTML.
Here is an example of dynamic IDs for container divs:
    <div id="replyLikesDiv">
                <img id="replyReviewsImg" src="{% static 'images/icons8-reply-arrow-50.png' %}">
                <div id="replyReviewsDiv">Ответить</div>

                <img class='likesReviewsImg' id="likesReviewsImg{{ REVIEWS_IDS }}" onclick="likesReviewsImgClick(this)" src="{% static 'images/icons8-facebook-like-50.png' %}">

                <div  class='likesReviewsDiv' id="likesReviewsDiv{{ REVIEWS_IDS }}" onclick="likesReviewsDivClick(this)">...</div></div>

<div class="likeAuthorizationDiv" id='likeAuthorizationDiv{{ REVIEWS_IDS }}'>

                <div id="likeAuthorizationMessage">Пожалуйста, авторизуйтесь, чтобы продолжить.</div>  
 
        <div  id="sendReviewBtnDiv2">
            <div id="sendReviewBtn2"">Закрыть</div>

            </div>
            </div>

REVIEWS_IDS is automatically loaded from the database and inserted using the Jinja template engine. REVIEWS_IDS is an integer value 1,2,3,4... and does not repeat, so all ids are unique.
By design, when you click id="likesReviewsDiv{{ REVIEWS_IDS }}", the likesReviewsDivClick() function is called. It looks like this:
function likesReviewsDivClick(el){
    var id = el.id;
    id = Number(id.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
    id = 'likeAuthorizationDiv' + id;
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    element.style.visibility = 'hidden';

    alert(element.style.visibility);
}

In the function, I read the ID and substitute it in likeAuthorizationDiv. Then, I get the element I need in the function and try to change its style to hidden. The style changes in the alert, but not on the page. What can be wrong?
I tried to change the style in many ways, but never figured out how to do it. As I understand it, the problem is in the DOM.
EDIT: So, if I put onclick attribute to id='likeAuthorizationDiv{{ REVIEWS_IDS }}' and make function likeAuthorizationDivClick(el), div container will become invisible. But it is not the solution for me.
HTML:
<div class="likeAuthorizationDiv" onclick='likeAuthorizationDivClick(this)' id='likeAuthorizationDiv{{ REVIEWS_IDS }}' >

JavaScript (this function works, but not the solution):
function likeAuthorizationDivClick(el){
    el.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}


But this doesn't work (It could be the solution for me):
function likeAuthorizationDivClick(el){
    var id = el.id;
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    element.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}


Are there any errors in your console? When I run your code in jsfiddle, the element becomes invisible.

i will check it now

there is no errors

What steps have you taken to debug this problem? In your last "could be the solution for me", you take the element, get its id, then get the element by its id; why not just set el.style.visibility = "hidden"? Are the rendered {{ REVIEWS_IDS }}` unique? Are all the IDs unique?

About el.style.visibility = 'hidden': it was my previous js code. I know about this opportunity, but i need complex structure of code, i cant explain it. All the {{ REVIEWS_IDS }}` unique. In my db 30 ids from 1 to 30. I checked them in html with js, all of them are correct

Let's see,
make sure your servers are properly ongoing as it can be a server problem as well . Try apps like VS Code or Scrimba or they provide a output window by the side of the code so you can monitor the changes at each step . Another problem may be the proper linking of the elements within different files. Make sure you link the pages properly . Or best of all try writing the code afresh or try an AI Bot to write it for you and you can study their patterns.
Hope it helps....
Thank you

everything is connected correctly

servers work correctly.

All the links between pages are properly too.
